# Define Method Signature that takes a function as parameter

Tags: typescript

I want to declare a Type Definition that this function  obeys:

```
var a : MyInterface = function(func : <T>(t: T) => number) {
  console.log("do Nothing");
  return func(123) + " someString";
}
```

What I am trying, is to build an Interface that takes *a function f returning a number as parameter* and returning a string itself. To my understanding, the Interface should look like this.

```
interface MyInterface {

    (func: (<T>(t: T) => number)) => string;
}
```

But it does not work, complaining about the final '=>', saying `':' expected`.

If I simply ommit the return type 'string', the compiler is happy. What can I do about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an interface the return type of a callable signature uses `:` instead of `=>`. So in your case it would be

```
interface MyInterface {
    (func: (<T>(t: T) => number)): string;
}
```

But if you only want to declare a function type it would be more straightforward to use the shorthand syntax which again uses `=>`.

```
type MyFunction = (func: (<T>(t: T) => number)) => string
```

The advantage of the former syntax is that it lets you define overload signatures and hybrid types that are not only callable but also have properties.